# connect switch handy box to plenum?

Tags: electrical, hvac, switch, furnace

would it be code to attach the 2 x 4 handy box with the switch on the plenum as the old furnace set up would hook up on the new furnace with the bx cable coming off bottom of handy box to furnace connection?
thanks for the assistance
[image: conduit to handy box, bx cable off bottom of handy box]

Comment: Code requires the wiring to be protected , NM exposed in this case is exposed and could be damaged where the old BX , AC or MC may be fine depending on your location.

Comment: thanks above the handy box is rigid conduit going to wire in joist area

Comment: It looks like the box is at a 45deg angle to the plenum.  How were you planning on securing it to the plenum, given that, or is it possible to have it flat against the plenum?

Comment: thanks, I intend to secure the handy box flat to plenum as I just have it hanging loose; but I can definitely attach it flat to the plenum; so, it's fine to attach the back of the handy box to the plenum?

Answer (score 1):

### As long as the box is rigidly supported and not putting load on cables, you're good to go

The basic goal of NEC 314.23 is that boxes shall not be supported in a way that puts strain on cables or wiring unless there's specific engineering (such as in a pendant drop setup) that compensates for the issue, both in the cable and the connection to the box.  So, screwing the box into the duct plenum should work, provided the result is a box that doesn't flop around in the breeze.